# how can play next song mediaplayer with click button notification

Tags: android, service, notifications, media-player

i want play next song in mediaplayer with click button notification services to play my song i use this code :

```
public void playSongWithIndex(final int songIndex) {

      try {
        G.mediaPlayer.reset();
        G.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).getFile_128());
        G.mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        G.mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            startService = new Intent(G.context, MediaPlayerService.class);
            startService.setAction(MediaPlayerService.ACTION_PLAY);
            G.context.startService(startService);
            G.mediaPlayer.start();   
            seekBar.setMax(G.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new MainTimer(), 0, 1000);

          }
        });
      }
```

and my service code :

```
@Override
    public void onSkipToNext() {
    super.onSkipToNext();
buildNotification(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE));

    }
```

please help how do this action?

Answer (score 0):

Read this article

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html

This notification style is specially for media:

"...you can promote up to 3 actions to be displayed in the standard view alongside the usual content."